# Размер шрифтов текстов всех View задавать в dp

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, если я буду делать размеры шрифтов в dp, то это нормальная практика?
Чтобы не было всяких казусов на разных экранах, особенно при установке огромных шрифтов на маленьких экранах, поскольку весь дизайн построен по размерам в dp, то логичнее и текст сделать в dp? Ну или запретить его масштабирование в системе.

```
// Фиксированный размер шрифтов текста для всех View(воде как)(масштабирование шрифтов работать не будет)
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public void Fixed_Size_ALL_Text(Context newBase) {
    final Configuration override = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
    override.fontScale = 1.0f;
    applyOverrideConfiguration(override);
}
```

Comment: А чем собственно, масштабирование не угодило? Может эту проблему решать, а не запрещать?

Comment: Если высота View фиксированная в dp, то зачем в нем шрифт менять, с точки зрения дизайна? Я посмотрел на примере приложения AIDA64, в ней всегда все одинаково, какие шрифты не выставляй в системе.. У меня тоже есть макеты списков с фиксированной высотой, где влезает три фиксированных TextView.. Когда я на маленьком смартфончике включил огромный шрифт, то ужаснулся результату. Взять ту же кнопку с заданными шириной и высотой в dp, зачем в ней микроскопический текст или наоборот не влезающий?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981260/should-use-sp-instead-of-dp-for-text-sizes

Comment: нужно решать проблему фиксированных размеров виджетов, а не масштабируемого текста. в андроид огромное количество типоразмеров и плотностей экранов и хардкорные размеры виджетов - это мрак. либо вы будете создавать десятки разметок и покроете ими с три четверти устройств (владельцы оставшейся четверти будут думать о вас плохое, смотря на ужасную поехавшую разметку), либо вы сверстаете под один экран и тогда почти все пользователи будут думать о вас все то же плохое. Должна быть одна адаптивная разметка под все экраны с динамическими размерами виджетов и масштабируемыми шрифтами

Comment: отдельное спасибо вам скажут пользователи с проблемами зрения, разглядывая ваши фиксированные шрифты, не реагирующие на системные настройки

Comment: pavlofff, ну разве в dp они не будут адекватно выглядеть? Я же изначально делаю размеры, чтобы нормально читалось и достаточно крупно, экраны у смартфонов почти одинаковые. Вот с планшетами, или экраны с очень высоким разрешением я не знаю как себя поведут, я тестю на 4,5 дюймовом экране 480х800, и 5,5 дюймовом 1080х1920. Так то я с вами согласен, но больно уж геморно поддерживать все экраны и сохранять дизайн..

Comment: все же гораздо менее геморно, чем писать десятки разметок под всевозможные типоразмеры и плотности, тестировать и подгонять их. новый контейнер ConstraintLayout располагает всеми возможностями адаптивной (резиновой) верстки, просто нужно освоить его в достаточной степени. Вообще, как бы есть устоявшаяся практика, написано огромное количество информации, зачем придумывать какой то свой "особенный" путь. кстати, посмотреть как будет выглядеть разметка на том или ином типоразмере экрана модно в визуальном редакторе очень быстро, переключая "устройства" вверху редактора

Comment: @pavlofff, и до ConstraintLayout все прекрасно версталось. С ним конечно проще и быстрее.